# Was Hadiya Nassar, an elderly Palestinian woman, killed by an Israeli sniper?

Tags: israel-hamas-war

[An article](https://www.newarab.com/news/palestinian-woman-older-israel-killed-israel) dated 09 December, 2023 from [*The New Arab*](https://www.newarab.com/news/palestinian-woman-older-israel-killed-israel) reports:

> An elderly Palestinian woman who went viral on social media after saying that she's "older than Israel" was shot dead by Israeli snipers outside her house.
>
> The woman, Hadiya Nassar, appeared in a video where Palestinian journalist Saleh Aljafarawi, holding her ID card, said, "you are older than Israel".
>
> [...]
>
> Aljafarawi [confirmed](https://twitter.com/S_Aljafarawi/status/1732665660444950819?s=20) her death on social media site X on Thursday, writing: "You were martyred, my beloved. May God have mercy on your and make your resting place Paradise."
>
> According to *Al Jazeera*, Aljafarawi's cousin, who was Nassar's neighbour, told him that she was killed by an Israeli sniper outside her front door.

Aljafarawi's tweet does not specify the cause of death. There is no link to the *Al Jazeera* article and I haven't seen a report from them in English. Does *Al Jazeera* actually report such a statement from the neighbor? Is there any other evidence that Israeli snipers are responsible for Nassar's death?

Comment: That's a strange claim, as there is nothing special about that woman that would justify, as the claim tries to suggest, a targeted attack specifically against her because of her claim. She is (or was) old, she isn't the only old person in the world, Palestinian or other, the fact that she was born before may 14, 1948 doesn't contradict any Israeli narrative. She was presumably killed in Gaza, in the middle of an active war. If she is dead, it's more probable that this is the result of regrettable collateral damage rather than a targeted attack against her specifically.

Comment: @SIMEL Neither the OP nor the original sources make the claim she was shot because of claiming being older than Israel. She was interviewed by a journalist, she was killed some days after and we don't know (and possibly can't know) whether this was a stray bullet or a sniper, or what.

Comment: @C.F.G IIRC your answer began with something like "This answer does not confirm or deny the claim", which is what answers here are *supposed* to do, so presumably it was flagged as "not an answer" and deleted for that reason.

Comment: I'm only speculating. If you want a definitive answer, I would recommend posting on [Meta](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/), asking *respectfully* why the answer was deleted and how you can improve it. @-ing Oddthinking here on the question isn't going to alert them - that only works if the user has previously commented.

Comment: @C.F.G: Please don't use the "But officer, other people were speeding" excuse. Two wrongs don't make a right. Flag the problem answers and/or post comments explaining why they are wrong.

Comment: @C.F.G: Your answer was speculation based on rumour. It didn't answer the question.

Comment: @Oddthinking The OP ask "Does Al Jazeera actually report such a statement". I don't speculate. I said how this rumor is possible and I provided the Aljazeera link. I emphasized that I neither confirm nor reject.

Comment: @C.F.G: Then edit it down to that. Remove statements like "it is at least obvious that Nassar's death is not the collateral damage of the air strike or similar cases."

Comment: @Oddthinking: When one talks to one's neighbor, isn't it clear that buildings have not been destroyed by fighter jets or tanks? I responded to the "SIMEL" comment.

Comment: @C.F.F Focus your answer on the question asked. Give references. Stop speculating. I am bowing out now.

Comment: @SIMEL _there is nothing special about that woman_ .. she become "Symbol of Palestine" because of she was older than Israel.

Comment: @C.F.G my grandmother is also older than the state of Israel, Beni Begin a former member of Knesset and the son of a former PM is older than the state of Israel, I'm older than all the of the states of former Yugoslavia and the USSR. No one argues that the Modern state of Israel was created before 1948. The existence of old people doesn't contribute to any narrative. Unless she was 1400 years old and claimed that she was a Palestinian Arab before the Muslim conquest of the land around 630 AD.

Comment: @Rekesoft the adjacency of the two statements "she was older than the state of Israel" and "killed by a sniper" reads to me that the post tries to suggest that she was killed in a targeted hit on her specifically because of her being a symbol. However we can know if it was a sniper or not, as snipers use a different caliber than regular infantrymen if the bullet that killed her was available, it could be checked. And the chances that a sniper killed her by a stray bullet is lower than a non sniper (it can still be an error in judgment or misidentification).

Comment: @SIMEL: Your comment shows that you still didn't understand what the issue of  Palestine is. By your argument, United States should give back the red (Indian) lands to them. Australia should give back Tasmania's lands to them. Bahrain Should give back its land to Iranians. Turkey should give back their land to Iranians? etc. Do you mean this?

Comment: @C.F.G No, and since it's irrelevant to the question at hand I'll not continue this discussion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question asks:

> Does *Al Jazeera* actually report such a statement from the neighbor?

Yes, *Al Jazeera* reported on this [December 7, 2023](https://www.aljazeera.net/misc/2023/12/7/%D9%85%D8%B5%D9%88%D8%B1-%D9%81%D9%84%D8%B3%D8%B7%D9%8A%D9%86%D9%8A-%D9%8A%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%86-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%B4%D9%87%D8%A7%D8%AF-%D8%B5%D8%A7%D8%AD%D8%A8%D8%A9-%D9%85%D9%82%D9%88%D9%84%D8%A9). However, their sources were merely Saleh Al-Jaafrawi's social media accounts (X and Instagram), which gives little reason to trust them:

> According to a conversation on Instagram that took place between [Saleh Al-Jaafrawi] and “Abi Julia,” one of the old woman’s neighbors, he said: “My cousin, who lives in the back street behind her, spoke to me and informed me that members of the Israeli army sniped at her at the door of her house.”
> [Google translate]